# how to manage two memory devices?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I just installed a new 240 GB SSD in my desktop pc with an existing HDD and cloned my OS into my new SSD(by searching on Youtube). How do I remove everything from my HDD so that I can use it to store other files? I am very new to ubuntu and don't know what to do.

Comment: I would suggest you be certain you have migrated your OS properly before you disposition your original HDD.  You should remove the HDD from the system and boot from your SSD alone to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu Desktop, you can use the "Disks" application. Choose the hard drive from the list on the side, and from there you can click the "gears" icon and choose "Format Partition".

Before doing this, it would be a good idea to confirm:

1. Your computer is booting from the SSDs, not the HDD
2. Your data is properly on the SSDs

So long as this is good, or so long as you have recent backups of your files (just in case), then format away.